# Python Tkinter move text to center of button but keep image to the top left corner

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, button

I would like to move the text to the center of the button but keep the image to the top left corner.
Does anybody know if this is possible?

Here below is my code that puts the image to the top left corner and the text to its left but I could not figure out a way to have the text to the middle of the button.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import font as tkFont
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

 
# Create the master object
root = tk.Tk()
 
# Sets the window size as "300x300"
root.geometry("300x300")
helv32 = tkFont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=32, weight='bold')
 
# This is the button callback function
# This must be visible to the button, so we must define it before the button widget!
def buttonCallback():
    messagebox.showinfo("Message", "You have clicked the Button!")
 
# Create a tk.PhotoImage
my_image = Image.open("./debian.png")
# Resize it to fit button dimensions
my_image = my_image.resize((25, 25), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)
# Finally, get the PhotoImage object
my_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(my_image)
 
# Create a Button widget
button = tk.Button(root, text=" Click", image=my_image, command=buttonCallback, compound=tk.LEFT, height = 300, width = 300, bg="lightblue",
                   font=helv32, anchor=tk.NW)
  
# Use the grid geometry manager to put the widgets in the respective position
button.grid(row=1, column=0)
 
# The application mainloop
root.mainloop()
```

I tried to follow [acw1668](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5317403/acw1668) suggestion and came up with the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageColor

root = tk.Tk()

root.update_idletasks()

root.wm_state("zoomed")
buttonWidth = root.winfo_width()
buttonHeight = root.winfo_height()

screenWidth = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screenHeight = root.winfo_screenheight()
screenText = f'Screen Width: {screenWidth}\nScreen Height: {screenHeight}'


def OnEnter(event, color: str):
    event.widget['background'] = color

def OnLeave(event, color):
    event.widget['background'] = color


def OnButtonResize(event, logoFile: str, imageWidth: int, imageHeight: int):

    buttonWidth = event.width
    buttonHeight = event.height

    # load the required image and resize it to the desired size
    logo = Image.open(logoFile).resize((imageWidth, imageHeight))
    # create a larger transparent image (around the size of the button)
    img = Image.new("RGBA", (buttonWidth, buttonHeight), (0, 0, 0, 0))
    # paste the small image at the top-left corner of this large image
    img.paste(logo)
    
    imgWidth, imgHeight = img.size
    buttonText = f'Button Width: {imgWidth}\nButton Height: {imgHeight}\n{screenText}'
    #print(buttonText)

    tkimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    
    event.widget['text'] = buttonText
    event.widget['image'] = tkimg


def Rgb2Hex(rgbTuple: tuple) -> str:
    return (f"#{rgbTuple[0]:02x}{rgbTuple[1]:02x}{rgbTuple[2]:02x}")


def Hex2Rgb(hexcode: str) -> tuple:
    return(ImageColor.getcolor(hexcode, "RGB"))


def clamp(x: int) -> int: 
  return max(0, min(x, 255))


def LightenHexColor(hexColorCode: str , percent: int = 10) -> str:
    
    inputColorTuple = Hex2Rgb(hexColorCode)
    
    ligtherColorTuple = ()
    for i in inputColorTuple:
        ligtherColorTuple = ligtherColorTuple + (clamp(int(i*(100+percent)/100)),)

    return(Rgb2Hex(ligtherColorTuple))


helv32 = ("Helvetica", 32, "bold")

global logo
global img
global tkimg
global button

logoFilename = "debian.png"
logoWidth = logoHeight = 300

# load the required image and resize it to the desired size
logo = Image.open(logoFilename).resize((logoWidth, logoHeight))
# create a larger transparent image (around the size of the button)
#img = Image.new("RGBA", (imageWidth, imageHeight), (0, 0, 0, 0))
# paste the small image at the top-left corner of this large image
#img.paste(logo, (int(imageSize/2), int(imageSize/2)))

tkimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(logo)
bgColorCursorOut = "#F00000"
bgColorCursorIn = LightenHexColor(bgColorCursorOut)

button = tk.Button(root, text=screenText, image=tkimg, compound="c", bg=bgColorCursorOut, font=helv32, width=buttonWidth, height=buttonHeight)
#button = tk.Button(root, text=screenText, bg="lightblue", font=helv32, width=screenWidth, height=screenHeight)
button.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

button.bind("<Configure>", lambda event: OnButtonResize(event, logoFilename, logoWidth, logoHeight))
button.bind("<Enter>", lambda event: OnEnter(event, bgColorCursorIn))
button.bind("<Leave>", lambda event: OnLeave(event, bgColorCursorOut))

root.mainloop()
```

Everthing seems to work fine if I comment out the line:

```
event.widget['image'] = tkimg
```

But with that line in I get the following errors:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\psestini\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_40344\3920381195.py", line 27, in <lambda>
    button.bind("<Enter>", lambda event: OnEnter(event, bgColorCursorIn))
  File "C:\Users\psestini\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_40344\1042462112.py", line 2, in OnEnter
    event.widget['background'] = color
  File "E:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1686, in __setitem__
    self.configure({key: value})
  File "E:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1675, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "E:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1665, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage55" doesn't exist
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\psestini\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_40344\3920381195.py", line 28, in <lambda>
    button.bind("<Leave>", lambda event: OnLeave(event, bgColorCursorOut))
  File "C:\Users\psestini\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_40344\1042462112.py", line 5, in OnLeave
    event.widget['background'] = color
  File "E:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1686, in __setitem__
    self.configure({key: value})
  File "E:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1675, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "E:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1665, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage55" doesn't exist
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\psestini\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_40344\3920381195.py", line 27, in <lambda>
    button.bind("<Enter>", lambda event: OnEnter(event, bgColorCursorIn))
  File "C:\Users\psestini\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_40344\1042462112.py", line 2, in OnEnter
    event.widget['background'] = color
  File "E:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1686, in __setitem__
    self.configure({key: value})
  File "E:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1675, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "E:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1665, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage55" doesn't exist
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\psestini\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_40344\3920381195.py", line 28, in <lambda>
    button.bind("<Leave>", lambda event: OnLeave(event, bgColorCursorOut))
  File "C:\Users\psestini\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_40344\1042462112.py", line 5, in OnLeave
    event.widget['background'] = color
  File "E:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1686, in __setitem__
    self.configure({key: value})
  File "E:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1675, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "E:\Programs\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1665, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage55" doesn't exist
```

Do you have any suggestion on my errors and how to modify the code to avoid them?

Thanks.

When I tried to add a second button the proposed solution showed a strange behavior.
The main window grew till the the first button filled the whole screen.
Down below is my code.
Does anybody know what Im doing wrong this time?

Thanks again.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageColor, ImageFont

root = tk.Tk()

root.update_idletasks()

root.wm_state("zoomed")
buttonWidth = root.winfo_width()
buttonHeight = root.winfo_height()/2

screenWidth = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screenHeight = root.winfo_screenheight()
screenText = f'Screen Width: {screenWidth}\nScreen Height: {screenHeight}'


def OnEnter(event, color: str):
    event.widget['background'] = color

def OnLeave(event, color):
    event.widget['background'] = color

def OnButtonResize(event, logo: str, imageWidth: int, imageHeight: int) -> None:
    
    buttonWidth = event.width
    buttonHeight = event.height

    #print(f"Button resized to {buttonWidth}x{buttonHeight}")
    # load the required image and resize it to the desired size
    # logo = Image.open(logoFile).resize((imageWidth, imageHeight))
    # create a larger transparent image (around the size of the button)
    img = Image.new("RGBA", (buttonWidth, buttonHeight), (0, 0, 0, 0))
    # paste the small image at the top-left corner of this large image
    img.paste(logo, (int(buttonWidth/50), int(buttonHeight/30)))
    
    imgWidth, imgHeight = img.size
    buttonText = f'Button Width: {imgWidth}\nButton Height: {imgHeight}\n{screenText}'
    #print(buttonText)

    tkimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    
    event.widget['text'] = buttonText
    event.widget['image'] = tkimg
    event.widget.image = tkimg    # This line is to make the image persistent and avoid errors due to garbage collector

def Rgb2Hex(rgbTuple: tuple) -> str:
    return (f"#{rgbTuple[0]:02x}{rgbTuple[1]:02x}{rgbTuple[2]:02x}")

def Hex2Rgb(hexcode: str) -> tuple:
    return(ImageColor.getcolor(hexcode, "RGB"))

def clamp(x: int) -> int:
    return(max(0, min(x, 255)))

def LightenHexColor(hexColorCode: str , percent: int = 10) -> str:
    
    inputColorTuple = Hex2Rgb(hexColorCode)
    
    ligtherColorTuple = ()
    for i in inputColorTuple:
        ligtherColorTuple = ligtherColorTuple + (clamp(int(i*(100+percent)/100)),)

    return(Rgb2Hex(ligtherColorTuple))

def GetZoneNameImage(zoneName: str = "Z1", fontColor: str = "#000000") -> str:
    
    imageFilename = f"{zoneName}.png"
    font_size = 128
    font_filepath = "C:/Windows/Fonts/calibrii.ttf"
    
    color = Hex2Rgb(LightenHexColor(fontColor, -25))

    font = ImageFont.truetype(font_filepath, size=font_size)
    mask_image = font.getmask(zoneName, "L")
    img = Image.new("RGBA", mask_image.size)
    img.im.paste(color, (0, 0) + mask_image.size, mask_image)  # need to use the inner `img.im.paste` due to `getmask` returning a core
    img.save(imageFilename, quality=100)
    
    return(imageFilename)

helv32 = ("Helvetica", 32, "bold")

logoWidth = 150
logoHeight = 110

bgColorCursorOut1 = "#38bab6"
bgColorCursorIn1 = LightenHexColor(bgColorCursorOut1)

logoFilename1 = GetZoneNameImage(zoneName="Z1", fontColor=bgColorCursorOut1)

# load the required image and resize it to the desired size
logo1 = Image.open(logoFilename1).resize((logoWidth, logoHeight))
tkimg1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(logo1)

bgColorCursorOut1 = "#38bab6"
bgColorCursorIn1 = LightenHexColor(bgColorCursorOut1)

button1 = tk.Button(root, text=screenText, image=tkimg1, compound="c", bg=bgColorCursorOut1, font=helv32)#, width=buttonWidth, height=buttonHeight)
#button = tk.Button(root, text=screenText, bg="lightblue", font=helv32, width=screenWidth, height=screenHeight)
#button1.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
button1.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=tk.TRUE)

button1.bind("<Configure>", lambda event: OnButtonResize(event, logo1, logoWidth, logoHeight))
button1.bind("<Enter>", lambda event: OnEnter(event, bgColorCursorIn1))
button1.bind("<Leave>", lambda event: OnLeave(event, bgColorCursorOut1))

bgColorCursorOut2 = "#FCBA03"
bgColorCursorIn2 = LightenHexColor(bgColorCursorOut2)

logoFilename2 = GetZoneNameImage(zoneName="Z2", fontColor=bgColorCursorOut2)

# load the required image and resize it to the desired size
logo2 = Image.open(logoFilename2).resize((logoWidth, logoHeight))
tkimg2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(logo2)

button2 = tk.Button(root, text=screenText, image=tkimg2, compound="c", bg=bgColorCursorOut2, font=helv32)#, width=buttonWidth, height=buttonHeight)
#button = tk.Button(root, text=screenText, bg="lightblue", font=helv32, width=screenWidth, height=screenHeight)
#button2.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
button2.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=tk.TRUE)

button2.bind("<Configure>", lambda event: OnButtonResize(event, logo2, logoWidth, logoHeight))
button2.bind("<Enter>", lambda event: OnEnter(event, bgColorCursorIn2))
button2.bind("<Leave>", lambda event: OnLeave(event, bgColorCursorOut2))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You need to save the reference of the image, otherwise it is garbage collected which causes the exception.  Add `event.widget.image = tkimg` (use an attribute to store the reference) after `event.widget['image'] = tkimg`.

Comment: Also you don't need to call `logo = Image.open(logoFile).resize((imageWidth, imageHeight))` inside `OnButtonResize()`.

Comment: Understood. Now it works flawlessly. Thank you very very much.

Comment: It is better to create new question if you have another issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a larger blank image (around the size of the button) and put the small image at the top-left corner.  Then use this combined image in the button.

Below is an example code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = tk.Tk()

helv32 = ("Helvetica", 32, "bold")

# load the required image and resize it to the desired size
logo = Image.open("debian.png").resize((50, 50))
# create a larger transparent image (around the size of the button)
img = Image.new("RGBA", (250, 250), (0, 0, 0, 0))
# paste the small image at the top-left corner of this large image
img.paste(logo)

tkimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
button = tk.Button(root, text="Click", image=tkimg, compound="c",
                   width=300, height=300, bg="lightblue", font=helv32)
button.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you vey much for your suggestion.
How would you change it if you wanted to make the button resizable to the size of the main window?

Comment: Simple way is to repeat the creation of the image after the button is resized, i.e. inside the callback of binding `<Configure>` event of the button.